# Issue with font rendering on Browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, google-fonts

I am building a React App using Material UI library.
I need to change the default font of the theme from Roboto to Overpass. To do that I imported the fonts using their library

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then I have defined it in the `createMuiTheme` function:

```js
  export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
      fontFamily: [
        '-apple-system',
        'BlinkMacSystemFont',
        '"Segoe UI"',
        'Overpass',
        '"Helvetica Neue"',
        'Arial',
        'sans-serif',
        '"Apple Color Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
        '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
      ].join(','),
      ... 
    }
  })
```

When I see the result on the browser (tested on Chrome, Brave, Firefox), all the text is rendered with a "padding" at the bottom. I said "padding" cause it's not an actual padding, it's like if the text is incorrectly defined. I tried also to change the line-height property, but it's not the issue.

This issue is clearly visible when you try to align element in the center (`inherit` is the default value, but it inherit a `center` value)

[image]

The image above is the default Button component of material UI without any edits on my side: as you can see, the text is clearly aligned higher.

Same issue happens if I use another font (Like Benne)

Anyone has an idea on how this can be solved?

**Edit**: If I use Poppins as font, this issue is not present

**Edit 2**: See a sample https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-vaughan-zvwq9

In the sample, I have placed a button, as well as a component aligned in the center. In both situation you will see the above mentioned error

Comment: Have you tried changing the line-height css property?

Comment: Yes, and the behavior is exactly the same

Comment: Can you check from which element/style the label inherits the align/justify?

Comment: From the above element, that gets the `align-items: center` property in the `.MuiButtonBase-root` class. The point is that the button is just an example. The same thing happens also in `<p>` or `<div>`

Comment: can you add a codesandbox in order to test it there and help you better?

Comment: @Apostolos thanks for suggestion. Codesandbox created

Comment: cant see the error at button. it seems vertically aligned correctly.

Comment: They are not for me https://ibb.co/z2jkB7B
Which browser / OS are you using?

Comment: tried it in both ff and chrome latest versions

Comment: @Apostolos try now. If you were using Windows or Mac it was skipping Overpass, but using a precedent font. I have fixed the code on codeSandbox. Tested also with https://lambdatest.com and I can see the issue

Comment: i don't know if it is a font issue, but you can try `.MuiButton-label {
  padding-top: 3px;
}` as a hack

Comment: @Apostolos it works for the button but not for all other elements of Material UI, and I cannot set a custom padding on each element, will be endless. I was hoping to find a reason why this is happening with this specific font. Thanks for your help!

Comment: maybe it is how the font is created since it works with other fonts

Comment: think will post an issue on their MaterialUI github, as it's a font from Google Font, so maybe others will have it too

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is an issue with Overpass. They were aware of this issue since 2019 and released a fix in a few months later ( see [issue#56](https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/Overpass/issues/56) ).

Not sure why, they're not re-building the latest release, but have only published the fix in their repo. The only way to have it fixed, so far, is to **get the files directly from the repo**, and not downloading the release.

I personally think that Google Fonts directly gets the font from their build (.zip file) and not from the actual repo, bringing the issue.

There's already a [request to publish an updated build](https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/Overpass/issues/75), currently ignored by dev team.